# gnuplotで不連続なカラーバーを作成したい

Tags: gnuplot

以下のページの最後に記載のある不連続のカラーバーをgnuplotで作成したいのですが、やり方がわからず、ご教授いただきたいです。

[不連続カラーバーの作成(Python)](https://hackmd.io/@h2tg95D2RP2ed-D8u-49Mg/S1moBqaRr)

カラーマップの作成方法や、カラーバーのメモリの範囲指定などのやり方はわかるのですが、不連続のカラーバーの作成方法がわかりません。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
gnuplot version 5.4

gnuplot> set pm3d map
gnuplot> set cbrange[-2:2]
gnuplot> set cbtics(-2,-1.9,-1,1,2) #この-2,-1.9,-1,1,2の間隔を均等にしたい。
gnuplot> splot[-2:2]sin(x*y)
```

(追記)
すみません、質問の仕方が悪かったです。
作成したいのは、以下の画像のような、値としては不連続だが、軸の表示の間隔としては均等なカラーバーです。カラーバーの表示をなんとかしたいです。
私が最初に示した例だと、-2のすぐ上に-1.9の表示があり、その後少し離れて-1の表示がありますが、これらの表示の間隔を一定にしたいです。

[image]

Comment: 古くて承認されてませんがこんな記事が参考になるかも。[Gnuplot Dividing the color bar in different sectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15091754/9014308)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。質問の内容を少し修正しました。もしご存知でしたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: つまり参照記事に書かれている`matplotlib`における`BoundaryNorm`に相当する機能があるか？ということですかね。[gnuplot Discussion/Help](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/discussion/5925/) の記事を検索するか新たに聞いてみるとかしてみてはどうでしょう？ どうにも無さそうならカラーバーとは関係無い単独の図形をカラーバーのように見せて組み込むくらいでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。”matplotlibにおけるBoundaryNormに相当する機能があるか？ということですかね”⇨はい、そういうことになります。もう少し調べてみます。

Comment: 実現したいカラーバーを使いやすい別のツールでイメージデータファイルとして作成し、それをmultiplotでもう一つの図として挿入するとか？ [gnuplot: How to insert image in graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67419355/9014308) グラフで表示したい内容の方はカラーバーを表示しないように設定して。

Answer (score 0):

グラフの色階層をグラデーションではなく離散的(?)に表示する方法は2種類あります。

```
set palette maxcolors 8
```

上のように`maxcolors`を指定する方法と、

```
set palette defined (-2 "black",\
                     -1 "black",\
                     -1 "red",\
                     0 "red",\
                     0 "orange",\
                     1 "orange",\
                     1 "yellow",\
                     2 "yellow")
```

上のように始点の色と終点の色に同一色を指定する方法です。
(`-1`と`0`に同一色の"red"を指定することで、その区間は均一の色で描画されます)

**サンプルコード**

```
$ gnuplot
Version 5.4 patchlevel 2

set pm3d map
set cbrange[-2:2]
set cbtics(-2,-1.9,-1,1,2)
set palette maxcolors 8
splot[-2:2]sin(x*y)        # 1回目
set palette defined (-2 "black",\
                     -1 "black",\
                     -1 "red",\
                     0 "red",\
                     0 "orange",\
                     1 "orange",\
                     1 "yellow",\
                     2 "yellow")
splot[-2:2]sin(x*y)        # 2回目
```

**実行結果**

1回目

[image: 1回目の結果]

2回目

[image: 2回目の結果]

**参考資料**

- [Defining a palette with discrete colors](http://www.gnuplotting.org/defining-a-palette-with-discrete-colors/comment-page-1/)
- [How to force color range in gnuplotの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36534535/8248751)

Comment: ご回答とサンプルプログラムありがとうございます。少し私のやりたいことと違いましたので、質問内容を編集しました。ご存知でしたらご教授いただけますと幸いです。